# How can I switch cursor from code to terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

*I am using VS CODE v1.63(34 bit) on windows 7. I have node installed for executing javascript in the terminal in vs code.*

Answer (score 1):

Try to use shortcut like this: `Control` +  `tilde` => `Ctr+~`

*Tested on Win10 and Ubuntu 20.04*